# Create a good looking PDF layout

Tags: tikz-pgf, layout

I would like to generate a PDF that looks something like this.

This layout includes a lot of graphical elements like lines, boxes, etc. So it might be a good idea to use TikZ for that. However, I ran into some problems recently, e.g. the two boxes on the second page are not nessessarily the same height if one of them has less elements than the other.

After strugling with this a lot, I'm asking myself if LaTeX is actually the suitable tool for such a task, because the output is not really text based.

Would you still suggest using latex for this, or would you use another tool to generate this?
Of course, the PDF is generated from any given data.

Thanks for your suggestions

[image]

Comment: I'd probably not use LaTeX but Corel Draw, Inkscape, etc. If you want to stick with LaTeX maybe have a look at the `xcoffin`package.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are fancier ways with `tcolorbox`, for example, but here, I provide `xyminipage` environment to specify the x-y dimensions and, optionally, the color, of the field into which your content goes.

EDITED to provide `\xyminipagemargin` support, `\headerrule`, and `\sffamily` to mimic look of OP's question.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\newenvironment{xyminipage}[3][white]
{%
 \begin{minipage}{#2}%
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0pt}%
 \textcolor{#1}{\rule[-\dimexpr#3-\baselineskip]{#2}{#3}}%
 \end{minipage}%
 \hspace{\xyminipagemargin}%
 \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr#2-2\xyminipagemargin}%
 \sffamily\ignorespaces
}{%
 \end{minipage}%
 \hspace{\xyminipagemargin}%
 \end{minipage}%
 \ignorespacesafterend
}
\newcommand\mylinebreak{\\[-.9pt]}
\newlength\xyminipagemargin
\setlength\xyminipagemargin{15pt}
\newcommand\headerrule[1]{\sbox0{#1}#1\par\hspace{-\xyminipagemargin}%
  \rule[3pt]{\dimexpr\xyminipagemargin+\wd0}{2.5pt}\par}
\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{minipage}{7in}% THIS IS YOUR PDF WIDTH
\begin{xyminipage}[green!50!black]{4in}{3in}
\color{white}
\headerrule{This is my content}

It does not take the full height
\end{xyminipage}
\begin{xyminipage}[black!70]{3in}{3in}
\color{white}
\headerrule{This is my right-box content}

It also does not take the full height

\vspace{1in}
But if it is a different height, the box heights still match.
\end{xyminipage}
\mylinebreak
\includegraphics[width=7in,height=2in]{example-image}
\mylinebreak
\begin{xyminipage}[cyan!10]{7in}{1in}
\headerrule{This is my otherwise very longish titled content}

It does not take the full height
\end{xyminipage}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a brochure or a presentation. You should be using the latex package beamer.  TikZ is to draw diagrams and illustrations which you would include in some other Latex class like an article, report, presentation, poster etc. In the example posted I don't see any need to draw  anything. You just have text and figures to arranged in a visually appealing manner.

> [Beamer](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) is just perfect. You will love the output.

*and never leave* $\LaTeX$  **fantasy land**

Comment: This seems to be the best option so far, because text (like the "Objektbeschreibung" on page 3) should also span multiple pages. I will also take a look to the poster package to produce these two boxes aligned next to each other.